# Reading in online xlsx file and its separate sheets using Python

Tags: python, download, xlsx

I would like to be able to pull the data in the different sheets from the following URL: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1D4H2OoHOFVPmCoyKBVCjxIl0Bt3RLYSz/edit#gid=759235062

Specifically, I want to read each sheet (Champions, Contenders, etc.) into their own data-frames. Being able to download the full xlsx file could also be a solution. I have not been able to download this file successfully either.

I have tried several methods, but they were only able to pull the default first page.

```
import pandas as pd
xlsx_url = 'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/'

sheet_id = '1D4H2OoHOFVPmCoyKBVCjxIl0Bt3RLYSz'

# this is how I have been trying to access other sheets, but it doesn't work

# sheet_id = '1D4H2OoHOFVPmCoyKBVCjxIl0Bt3RLYSz/#gid=1234739310'

df = pd.read_csv(f'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/%7Bsheet_id%7D/export?format=csv', sep='delimiter', header=None, engine='python')
```

This approach works to get the first sheet, but is unable to read the others.

One workaround I have tried is to download the xlsx file and then work with it locally. However, this downloads a version that I cannot open for some reason.

```
import requests

xlsx_url = 'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1D4H2OoHOFVPmCoyKBVCjxIl0Bt3RLYSz'

response = requests.get(xlsx_url)

if response.status_code == 200:
with open('data.xlsx', 'wb') as file:
file.write(response.content)
```